# In this picture, would __A__ or __AB__ be an edge

Tags: geometry

[image: Square with diagonals]

In this picture, would the whole line *AB* be considered an edge, or only *A*

Comment: Can you please provide some more context to this question. The meaning of 'edge' changes within mathematics and either answer could be true based on context.

Comment: Not to mention, I have never seen the notation AB to mean the union of two colinear line segments before.  Your meaning is almost open to interpretation enough to be indecipherable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an edge is a line segment that joins two vertices, the only line segment here is AB. However, AB is not an edge, it is a diagonal because while it does join two vertices it passes through the interior of the square (keep in mind a square has just 4 edges).

Comment: Suppose the x was outside of a square. Would it still be considered an edge?

Comment: What do you mean? AB would still be a diagonal if it passed through the exterior of the square.

Comment: Ahhh I understand now @Colbi